# Как выравнять текст по центру в Label (LibGDX)

Tags: libgdx

Как выравнять текст по центру в Label? Сейчас текст прилеплен к левому краю, как выравнять его по центру?

Comment: Сейчас выглядит примерно так:
http://forpics.ru/i/20140804/623d7cc.jpg
Я хочу чтобы выглядело так:
http://forpics.ru/i/20140804/d9e07a7044f8.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Если все еще требуется ответ на вопрос, то у `Label` есть метод `setAlignment(int)`. Передаем значение из `Align`. Для выставления текста по центру нужно написать `setAlignment(Align.center)`.